# Simple question about convergence a.e

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

How could following property be proved without using Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Let  $\left\{{f_n(x)}\right\}$ ($f_n:\mathbb{R^m}\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$) be a sequence of functions such that $f_n\rightarrow{f}\;a.e$  and $|f_n|\leq{g}$ with $g$ an integrable function.
Then $f_n\rightarrow{f}$ in $L_1(\mathbb{R^n})$.

Does someone know a counterexample if it isn't true the second condition?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question basically is: Prove the dominated convergence theorem without using the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Ok ok. I understand

Comment: So for a proof, just look at any basic measure theory book (Rudin's POMA/RCA - Folland's Real analysis - Royden's Real analysis are examples that come to mind).

Answer (score 0):

The property you are stating *is* the Dominated Convergence theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

A simple counter example is the sequence of functions $f_n: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f_n(x) := \mathbb 1_{[n,n+1[}.$$
Then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, but $$\int\lvert f_n - 0 \rvert \, d\lambda = 1 \quad \forall n\in \mathbb N.$$
Note that there does not exist an integrable $g$ as in the statement of your property.